# Entity Framework Generic CRUD over SOAP WCF

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern

I'm writing a WCF service, built on top of an Entity Frameworks ORM.

The two clients for the service are a Web Application (not the client) and a Windows Service.

I have used the RepositoryPattern in the past to simplify the CRUD code WITHIN A service.
Is it possible to do this over WCF?

I have around a dozen objects that I need to perform CRUD on, so ideally I'd like a ServiceContract along the lines of:

```
IQueryable<T> GetAll();
IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
virtual void Add(T entity);
virtual void Delete(T entity);
virtual void Edit(T entity);
virtual void Save();
```

Is this sort of thing possible in WCF? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WCF Data Services - it doesn't use SOAP but OData (REST) but it provides what you need out of the box. With standard SOAP WCF service you will have to write whole serialization of Expression tree into SOAP request and reconstruct it into Linq query on the server.

Other option is ASP.NET Web-API which also supports `IQueryalbe` used on clients out of the box.

Comment: I have only ever used or seen WCF Data Services as a means for accessing data from a client app -can you point me in the direction of a reference for consumuing an OData Service in a C# server-side application.

Comment: That is exactly the same. Server app is still just OData client.

Comment: I've found e.g. WCF Data Services Client Library, but that relies on HTTP protocol - I cannot use this as the WCF service is hosted in a Windows Service.

Comment: WCF Data service is just a special type of WCF REST service and it can be hosted in any type of .NET application. Also any type of .NET application can expose service using HTTP if you configure your system correctly (netsh for enabling HTTP listener on selected port).

Comment: OK thanks - I didn't know that you could do that. Have you any idea how this compares with the performance of TCP binding?